# Work together on a same repository

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, repository

The workflow in our company is way too heavy (we're not using VCS). A very old school way of thinking. I'm trying to convince them to use GIT, but there are some points I would clarify first:

We work on many projects at the same time. Most of them are the same web application, but they have remarkable differences among them.

So what we all do is to work with the Eclipse IDE directly on virtual units (one per project) mounted on the development servers of each. When we finish any changes made to a project, and everything is working in the development server after testing it: We first backup the remote files which were changed, and next upload the changed files to the production server. A very primitive workflow, I know.

My question is, could we use GIT while still working directly on the virtual units mounted from the development servers? Or is it necessary to have a local copy of the repo on each worker's machine? This should force us to download lots of projects to our own local machines. Maybe GIT would allow us all to work directly on the same repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (with caution), but **must not** use ANY VCS this way: it's more headache, than fun, it's error-prone and badly manageable way

Your way is ANTIpattern and lazy way to development hell

Comment: Yes, I know it's a nightmare, I did use Subversion in my previous job, but here we work that kind of prehistoric way.

Comment: So your only recommendation would be to always work everyone locally (with local repos), and then push to the development server?

Comment: @user3514092 - local repository, maybe central push-target for easy aggregation of changes, deploy into live from *-hook

Comment: The central push target you mention, should be the project's development server? Once we commit any changes locally, should we push to this location, then test the application?

Comment: @user3514092 - "It depends". In common case, central repository and dev-server can be different unrelated hosts (because task of deploying code from repository is separate job, not a part of SCM per se). And selected publish|deploy policy is heavy-dependent from common workflow, tastes and habits. In common I consider auto-push in commit as "Bad Idea" (tm) - code must become public "on demand" b by hand, when it ready to be shared